# Holder-type inequality or not (optimal transport in Riemannian manifolds)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, riemannian-geometry, holder-inequality, optimal-transport

I'm reading a paper about optimal transport on Riemannian manifolds, and I came into a part where the author talks about "distortion coefficients". Here there's an inequality that I don't know how to prove it (I tried but I get contradictions):
\begin{align*}
(a+b)^{\frac{N-1}{N}}(c+d)^{\frac{1}{N}}\geq a^{\frac{N-1}{N}}c^{\frac{1}{N}}+b^{\frac{N-1}{N}}d^{\frac{1}{N}}\qquad\mbox{with}\quad a,b,c,d>0.
\end{align*}
He states that he used the Holder inequality with $p=\frac{N}{N-1}$ and $q=N$.

Comment: Are you sure about the $b$ and $c$?  The RHS should be $a^{(N-1)/N}c^{1/N}+b^{(N-1)/N}d^{1/N}$ instead.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the correction, my error. But anyways I'm confused on how to used the inequality he talks about.

Comment: Note the LHS is the product of the $p$-norm of $(a^{1/p},b^{1/p})$ and the $q$-norm of $(c^{1/q},d^{1/q})$, and apply Hölder.

Comment: Oh, I felt so dumb. Thank you, i was overthinking it!